# facing error of bad request even thought the query is same

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Well i am trying to reduce the line of code at once refactoring the code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Loader } from '../../components';
import './ProductListing.scss';
import { ProductCard } from '../../components';
import { productQuery } from '../../utls/queries';

export class ProductListing extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      products: [],
      categoryId: '',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const currentUrl = window.location.pathname;
    const id = currentUrl.replace('/', '');
    this.setState({ categoryId: id });
    const newQuer = { ...productQuery };
    const query = `
    query{
      categories {
          name
          products {
            id,
            name,
            brand,
            inStock,
            gallery,
            category,
            prices {
                amount,
                currency {
                  label,
                  symbol
                }
              }
          }
        }
  }
    `;
    console.log(query === productQuery);
    console.log(productQuery);
    fetch('http://localhost:4000', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        query,
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          products: data.data,
          loading: false,
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading === true) {
      return <Loader />;
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2 className='page__listing__title'>
            {this.state.categoryId[0].toUpperCase() +
              this.state.categoryId.substring(1)}
          </h2>
          <div className='productlisting__page'>
            {this.state.products.categories.map((item, index) => (
              <div key={index}>
                {item.name === this.state.categoryId ? (
                  <div className='product__listing__card'>
                    {item.products.map((product, i) => (
                      <ProductCard product={product} key={i} />
                    ))}
                  </div>
                ) : (
                  ''
                )}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default ProductListing;
```

In the process of reducing code i see that the query is taking a lot of places so i decided to write it at separate place now i am importing it as productQuery when i `console.log(productQuery===query)` it says true but the place where i am using the query to fetch data i use productQuery it just give bad error i cant understand ...
if some one have much better idea i really like if you can suggest me much better ways by which i can reduce the lines of code

[image]

Comment: What is the „bad error“ you are getting?

Comment: just updated the error image

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening is you're accidentally destructuring the query you import, when you say

```js
const newQuery = {...productQuery}
```

productQuery is simply a string (as proven by your console log that stays productQuery === query).

`newQuery` is an object that destructures the string, and trying to use that would likely result in a failure.

Comment: its not true i added it later by having a thought that it might changing or something actually i dont remember why exactly i added it is not working even if i remove it have added the error image